# Problems adding one project to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

When my project  ProjFlight  in folder Flight and I'm adding another project Proj4 to it (adding  by drag Proj4.xcodeproj in xcode and add library libProj4.a ) all works. But when I move my project  ProjFlight  into another folder saveFolder and do the same operation to add project Proj4 to it  apears an error. 
at #import "proj_api.h".
 "proj_api.h" file not found.
What can I do to fix it?
Project Proj4 can be in any folder.In both cases when ProjFlight is in folder Flight and ProjFlight is in folder saveFolder

Comment: Have you solve this,If you solve this then post answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your include file search path in project settings are correct